# c# winforms .net core 5.0 - how to capture a menu item click event

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I'm trying to move an existing c# WinForms .Net Framework app (4.8) to a WinForms Core (5.0) app. I'm stuck on capturing menu events.

I added a menu strip to Form1 and added the standard items. I can even add or remove menu items, reorder them, etc.

What I can't figure out how to do is capture the click event.

I can capture the top level menu items (File, Edit, Tools, Help), but none of the sub menu items. Am I going to have to go into the designer and wire that up by hand?

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an event to a `ToolStripMenuItem` works in the same way as adding events to other classes (e.g. `this.toolStripMenuItem1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.ToolStripMenuItem1_Click);`). So, yes, you will need to either add this to your code or wire it up in Designer. Unfortunately, Designer doesn't allow you to click on the drop-down buttons itself, so you'll need to use the drop-down in the Properties window to do so (or just add the snippet to your constructor.)

To add the item to the menu, just call either `ToolStripDropDownButton.DropDownItems.Add` (for single items) or `ToolStripDropDownButton.DropDownItems.AddRange` (for arrays). The auto-generated code uses `AddRange` regardless of the number of elements. Note that you shouldn't access the items' events or properties through `DropDownItems`; instead, declare the items seperately (the designer does that for you) and access those instead.